# Проверьте пожалуйста моё сочинение

Tags: обучение

(1)Чем дольше живу, тем больше поражаюсь тому, что можно назвать вероятностью в человеческой жизни. (2)Вот уж где нет никаких закономерностей — безраздельно господствует случайность! (3)Ну, скажем, такая до банальности очевидная, как наше появление на свет.

(4)Ведь уже само рождение человека — результат совершенно непредвиденной, непредсказуемой цепочки случайного! (5)Разве не случайность, что ранее не знакомые между собой люди вдруг встретились в определённое время, в определённом месте и потом дали жизнь новому человеку? (б)Человеку абсолютно неповторимому, уникальному, которого никогда не было на Земле раньше и никогда не будет потом.

(7)Разве это не удивительно? (8)И это только самый близкий результат случайного в судьбе каждого человека. (9)А дальние «вероятности» нашей судьбы и проследить до конца невозможно — они уходят к пращурам, в глубину веков. (Ю)Какая же неисчислимая череда случайных встреч, жизненных ситуаций, переплетений человеческих судеб, природных и социальных катаклизмов (войн, революций, переселений народов и т.п.) должна была сложиться в мозаику неповторимых комбинаций, чтобы именно этому, конкретному человеку было даровано такое удивительное чудо — жизнь! (11)И как же бездарно и бездумно мы порой относимся к этому прекрасному, но, в общем-то, такому ... чуду!

(12)А ведь есть другие — совершенно поразительные примеры.

(13)Жил-был необычный человек — крестьянин села Утевка Самарской губернии Григорий Журавлёв (1858—1916). (14)Судьба послала ему ужасные испытания! (15)Он родился без рук и ног и был обречён на жалкое, животное существование. (16)Но ещё в детстве он захотел рисовать. (17)И стал писать иконы. (18)Сегодня их можно увидеть в Троице-Сергиевой лавре, в Казанском соборе Петербурга, в других храмах России, одну из его икон недавно обнаружили даже в Боснии.

(19)А в конце жизни Григорий Журавлёв стал расписывать церковь в своём селе. (20)Привязанный под куполом, часами лежал он на спине и расписывал сантиметр за сантиметром, держа кисть в зубах.

(21)От нечеловечески тяжёлого труда спина и затылок покрывались кровавыми язвами. (22)Трескались губы. (23)Кровоточил рот. (24)Но он выполнял своё предназначение.

(25)Наверное, каждый человек задумывается о смысле своей жизни. (26)Но дальше благих намерений что-то изменить в ней (с понедельника, с Нового года...) дело чаще всего не идёт. (27)Мы или не понимаем огромную ценность дарованного нам чуда, или относимся к нему легкомысленно и, по сути, предаём этот дар, разменивая свою жизнь на ничтожные дела и чувства. (28)Прекрасно сказал Афанасий Фет:

(29)Не жизни жаль с томительным дыханьем,
 Что жизнь и смерть? (30)А жаль того огня,
 Что просиял над целым мирозданьем,
 И в ночь идёт, и плачет, уходя.

(31)Увидеть этот огонь в себе, не дать ему затухнуть в повседневной суете — вот что, по-моему, очень важно.

(По Н. Михайлову)

А вот и моё сочинение
 В своём тексте Н. Михайлов поднимает проблему жизни как удивительного чуда.
 Эта проблема,на мой взгляд,очень актуальна,потому что многие люди живут,не задумываясь о том,как им было послано такое дарование как жизнь. Автор рассуждает о том, что в мире "безраздельно господствует случайность"! К примеру он приводит такую вещь как наше появление на свет. Люди встретились в определённое время и месте и дали жизнь новому человеку. Это даже не совсем случайность, а подчинение какого-нибудь закона или правила. Другими словами можно сказать,что случайность - это вовремя не выявленная закономерность. Н. Михайлов также считает,что каждый человек должен что-то сделать в своей жизни,чтобы она не была прожита впустую. В качестве примера автор рассказывает о жизни калеки Григория Журавлёва,который не имея ни рук, ни ног,смог всё же заниматься любимым делом.
 Публицист считает,что человек часто или не понимает ценность дарованной ему жизни, или относится к ней легкомысленно. Ведь мы рождены,чтобы реализовать свои силы, заложенные в нас природой,чтобы плодами своих трудов радовать людей.
 На примере Григория Журавлёва хочу рассказать похожую историю. Она описывается Б.Н. Полевым в произведении "Повесть о настоящем человеке" Главный герой Алексей Мересьев управлял самолётом при помощи протезов. Герой повести Бориса Полевого - действительно настоящий человек! Мересьев пример того,как человек благодаря собственной силе воли,настойчивости,целеустремлённости преодолевает трудности и идёт к своей цели. Ведь жизнь одна,это удивительно чудо, и нужно в любых обстоятельствах бороться с кознями судьбы,не опускать руки и ценить это прекрасное дарование с небес

Помогите пожалуйста написать пример из жизненного опыта

Answer (score 1):

Это Вы  нафантазировали, здесь нет такой проблемы, вряд ли примут.Их здесь две:

1. Проблема случайности и закономерности(вероятности) в человеческой жизни.
2. Проблема смысла жизни.

Вы их соединили в одной, но совсем отличной от авторского замысла.

Позиция автора:

1. В жизни человека безраздельно господствует случайность.
2. Человек часто или не понимает ценность дарованной ему жизни, или относится к ней легкомысленно.(Или:"31)Увидеть этот огонь в себе, не дать ему затухнуть в повседневной суете — вот что, по-моему, очень важно").

Нужно разделить проблемы. По-моему, легче писать по второй - аргументов о смысле жизни можно найти больше.Смысл жизни человека - выполнять своё предназначение,"реализовать свои силы, заложенные в нас природой,чтобы плодами своих трудов радовать людей". Народоволец Н.Кибальчич был приговорён к смерти за покушение на царя.Ожидая смерти, он работал над проектом реактивного двигателя. Больше, чем собственная жизнь, его заботила судьба изобретения.Перед казнью он отдал жандарму чертежи и космического аппарата и просил передать их учёным.

Выполнял своё предназначение калека Г.Журавлёв, выполнял своё предназначение А. Мересьв, лётчик,отморозивший ноги,  но знавший, что ничего другого так хорошо он в жизни делать не будет, как летать, вынес множество операций и огромным усилием воли заставил свой организм продолжать летать, потому что это его предназначение, смысл жизни.А вот герои Горького в "На дне" потеряли смысл жизни и  опустились на дно, потеряв человеческий облик.

Answer (score 1):

В учебнике Репкина для младших классов (развивающее обучение)  рассказывается о том, какую грамматическую структуру мы считаем текстом. Он полагает, что  текст должен соответствовать  трем показателям: все высказывания  должны иметь ОБЩИЙ ПРЕДМЕТ (признак самостоятельности), в тексте должно быть ГЛАВНОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ, ИЛИ ОСНОВНАЯ МЫСЛЬ (признак целостности), и эта МЫСЛЬ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ РАСКРЫТА  (признак законченности). Если непонятно, что хотел сказать автор, то это не текст, а часть текста.

1. О ТЕКСТЕ. Если следовать этим указаниям, то в тексте НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ДВУХ САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРОБЛЕМ – все проблемы должны быть связаны между собой общим предметом и главной мыслью. Поэтому проблема случайности и проблема смысла жизни должны иметь общую идею.  А вот найти эту общую идею в предлагаемом  тексте  не так просто. Совсем не очевидно следующее утверждение автора: жизнь – это случайность, поэтому к жизни   нельзя относиться бездарно и бездумно. И переход от первой части текста ко второй  обозначен как-то неубедительно.
2. О СОЧИНЕНИИ ПО ТЕКСТУ. А если  это так, то автор сочинения по тексту имеет право высказать свое мнение и свое понимание главной мысли. Например, он считает, что есть связь между случайным и закономерным. Человеку не дано понять эту связь, поэтому он считает жизнь чудом и полагает, что нам  дана эта возможность с определенной целью – высказать себя в творчестве. Если автор сочинения  именно это имел в виду, то он высказал свою мысль понятно и вполне достойно. Другое дело, что сочинение содержит много грамматических неточностей, то есть автору здесь есть над чем поработать.
3. Меня всегда огорчает, когда школьникам не дают свободно высказать свою точку зрения, то есть поправляют его мысли. Я считаю, учитель должен прежде всего править форму, если он считает ее не соответствующей содержанию.

ОТВЕТ 2.
К ЕГЭ я никого не готовлю - не люблю псевдознаний.  Угадать и угодить – вот основные принципы этого мероприятия в настоящий момент, причем угодить не общим критериям правильного текста, а плодам мыслительной деятельности чиновников от литературы. К самой идее ЕГЭ я отношусь положительно, так как в нем есть неплохие потенциальные возможности. Но увы! У нас что ни делается, «все идет как-то не так». Государство  заинтересовано в подготовке «населения» к правильному мышлению не далее «пяти проблем», поэтому, наверное, разумно прислушаться к Вашим советам.

Comment: А Вы давно готовили к ЕГЭ? Основное правило: Определить все проблемы, но написать ОБ ОДНОЙ ИЗ НИХ.Есть 5 проблем в тексте, но проверяющим даны ключи, и если среди них нет вашей, вам поставят 0 баллов за проблему, а значит, и по критериям К2-К4 тоже.Потеряете сразу 7 баллов из 23. Проблема жизни как удивительного чуда там слегка затронута: жизнь как чудо - результат совпадения случайностей.